# Mysql LOAD DATA trucate column

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a classic city list in my table. I'm using Mysql 5.7.22-log on AWS RDS.
This is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_i22k5i5v70edpr8sn0f7qsqu8` (`sid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UKprra9tj5gtk21kc3chb9skup9` (`name`,`district`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8192 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I've a UTF-8 .csv file as this:

```
name;district;zipCode;region;country
Abano Terme;PD;35031;Veneto;IT
Abbadia Cerreto;LO;26834;Lombardia;IT
Abbadia Lariana;LC;23821;Lombardia;IT
Abbadia San Salvatore;SI;53021;Toscana;IT
```

I'm importing data in this way:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\City.csv' INTO TABLE City FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES
(NAME,district,zipCode,region,country)
SET `createdBy`='system',createdDate=NOW(),lastModifiedBy='system',lastModifiedDate=NOW(),sid=UUID(),`version`=1;
```

Data are imported, however I've a lot of warnings of truncated data:

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 1 warnings

Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\City.csv' INTO TABLE City FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES (n...

8103 row(s) affected, 8100 warning(s)

Execution Time : 0.309 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.002 sec
Total Time     : 0.312 sec

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 1

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 2

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 3

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 4

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 5

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 6

Note Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'country' at row 7
```

I don't see why, in the csv file the contry value is 2 char.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at what data was loaded?

By default, `LOAD DATA` assumes lines are terminated by a linefeed character, but MSWindows (inhieriting from MS-DOS, inheriting from CPM) uses a carriage return and linefeed as a line terminator. So it is seeing:

```
name;district;zipCode;region;country\r
Abano Terme;PD;35031;Veneto;IT\r
Abbadia Cerreto;LO;26834;Lombardia;IT\r
Abbadia Lariana;LC;23821;Lombardia;IT\r
Abbadia San Salvatore;SI;53021;Toscana;IT\r
```

Try:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\City.csv' 
INTO TABLE City 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(NAME,district,zipCode,region,country)
SET `createdBy`='system'
,createdDate=NOW()
,lastModifiedBy='system'
,lastModifiedDate=NOW()
,sid=UUID()
,`version`=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting you clearly, you need to change length of `country` attribute more than two in City table, Like below.

```
`country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: I don't want to change the length of the column on my DB. It's right it is 2 char. It's the ISO code of the country.